getSession returns null doing GitHub OAuth
Why is getSession returning null here? Can anyone tell me about this error? I am using GitHub OAuth, but the session is throwing null.
I am not using any form, just using GitHub OAuth and Google OAuth.
    // layout.js file:

    import type { Metadata } from "next";
    import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
    import "./globals.css";
    import SessionWrapper from "../components/Session-Wrapper";
    import  Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
    import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"; 
    
    const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
    
    export const metadata: Metadata = {
      title: "Create Next App",
      description: "Generated by create next app",
    };
      
    export default async function RootLayout({
      children,
    }: {
      children: React.ReactNode;
    }) {
      const session = await getSession(); 
      console.log("session is: " + session);
      
    
      return (
        <html lang="en">
          <body className={inter.className}>
            <SessionWrapper session={session}>
              <div className="overflow-hidden">
                <div className="h-[10vh]">
                  <Navbar />
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col max-h-min bg-slate-950">
                  {children}
                </div>
              </div>
            </SessionWrapper>
          </body>
        </html>
      );
    }

    // session-wrapper.tsx file:

    "use client"
    import React from 'react';
    import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
    
    type SessionWrapperProps = {
      children: React.ReactNode;
      session: any;
    };
    
    const SessionWrapper: React.FC<SessionWrapperProps> = ({ children, session }) => {
      return (
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          {children}
        </SessionProvider>
      );
    };
    
    export default SessionWrapper;

These is the output in the console:

GitHub repo:- https://github.com/TanmayChaurasia24/FundMe

According to the documentation of next-auth/react.
getSession is client side method, you are accessing the getSession at the layout file which is not a client side component, hence why it is returning null.
In your use-case, you should use next-auth's getServerSession.
